# How are control points referenced in this implementation for drawing a curve?

Tags: c++, curve

As an assignment, I have to implement De Casteljau Algorithm in order to draw a Bezier Curve. I understand fully how this algorithm works, and how it produces the curve, but I am failing to understand the coded implementation of the algorithm I have been given to work with.

The assigment consists of 3 parts:

1. Drawing some number of control points as well as the edges connecting them.
2. Implementing De Casteljau Algorithm for a given parameter `t` in the range [0, 1] which will draw all of the De Casteljau lines and the Bezier point according to this parameter. This is done in a function called `drawDeCasteljau`
3. Draw the curve by iterating from `t = 0.0` to `t = 1.0` and passing each `t` into `drawDeCasteljau` and painting each Bezier point. This is done in a function called `drawBezierCurve`

The program will then work in the following way:

- Click to add a point and an edge from the last point to this new point
- Click and hold a point to drag it around
- Press `+` or `-` to increment or decrement `t`. (This is where I currently am)
- Press `1` to display the De Casteljau lines and Bezier point for the current value of `t`
- Press `2` to paint the entire curve

The sample algorithm we have been given to use is:

```
int numPoints = 3;
Point bezPoints[numPoints][numPoints];

void DrawBezier() {
    for (float u = 0.0; u <= 1.0; u += 0.01) {
        for (int diag = numPoints - 2; diasg >= 0; diag--) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= diag; i++) {
                int j = diag - i;
                bezPoints[i][j] = (1.0 - u)*bezPoints[i][j + 1] + u*bezPoints[i + 1][j];
            }
         }
         setPixel(bezPoints[0][0]);
     }
}
```

I am completely lost with the `bezPoints` matrix and the lack of reference to any control points / lines in the algorithm.

Should `bezPoints` already be filled with the points before `DrawBezier()` is executed?

If I have 3 control points, why is `bezPoints` a 3x3 matrix? What exactly are these 9 points it is storing?

How does the algorithm work without ever referencing the control points / lines?

**EDIT**

Thanks to Nico's help below, I have managed to draw the Bezier curve:

[image]

However, I am still struggling to understand how to complete step 2 above in order to draw each of the De Casteljau lines used to find the Bezier point for the current value of `t`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control points should be in the farthest diagonal of the matrix `bezPoints`. You just have to get used to the indexing. Here is how it works: If you have `numPoints = 3`, the control points should be at diagonal 2, i.e. `bezPoints[0][2], bezPoints[1][1], bezPoints[2][0]`:

```
i \ j | 0 | 1 | 2
------+---+---+---
   0  |         C
   1  |     C
   2  | C
```

The loop over `diag` fills the other diagonals, i.e. the intermediate points after applying one iteration of the algorithm:

```
i \ j | 0 | 1 | 2
------+---+---+---
   0  |D=0 D=1  C
   1  |D=1  C
   2  | C
```

And then, the final point is at `bezPoints[0][0]`.

The variable `u` represents the curve parameter.

Comment: So should I be manually filling this diagonal with the control points before the algorithm in question is executed? Perhaps in between the lines declaring `bezPoints` and `DrawBezier` have a loop that iterates through this diagonal and through the control points, referencing each point in each element of the diagonal?

Comment: Ok, so your explanation has allowed me to figure out how to get each Bezier Point and hence how to draw the entire curve. I have no completed parts 1 and 2 listed above, but am strugglung to understand how to draw each pf the individual lines to find the Bezier Point. In other words, how to draw the red and yello lines in this image: http://www.e-cartouche.ch/content_reg/cartouche/graphics/en/image/casteljau/casteljau5.jpg

Comment: The black line is the control polygon and formed from the points on the outermost diagonal. The red line is formed by the points on the next diagonal (`D=1`) and so on. Note that the picture shows a curve of degree 3, whereas your code produces a curve of degree 2 (you have three control points).

Comment: Yes I figured it out in the mean time. The trouble behind my misunderstanding was figuring out where the different points are located in the matrix (the sturcuture of the matrix). Once this was figured out, I simply had to replace the line `bezPoints[i][j] = ...` with `drawEdge(bezPoints[i][j + 1], bezPoints[i + 1][j]` in the original algorithm.